# How to send this PUT-request to prestashop?

Tags: php, xml, rest, f#, prestashop

I am working with [Prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/) web service. I am trying to send a PUT (update) request to the API but with no luck. My request seems to be set up in the 'wrong' way (i.e. not in the way the server expects) Since Prestashop is open-source I took a look at the source code, specifically when it recieves a `PUT` request it does the following (I don't write php-code):

```
$input_xml = null;
// if a XML is in PUT or in POST
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {
    $putresource = fopen("php://input", "r");
    while ($putData = fread($putresource, 1024)) {
        $input_xml .= $putData;
    }
fclose($putresource);
  }
if (isset($input_xml) && strncmp($input_xml, 'xml=', 4) == 0) {
    $input_xml = substr($input_xml, 4);
}
```

From the code above I understood that my data should look something like this: `xml=<data><here></here></data>` but I don't know where to put this, should it be in the request-body or embedded in the url? is the "xml=" implicit when you send a request with `Content-Type = text/xml`? I did try different combinations of the request and still getting the same `404` error. I tried this:

```
let updateOrderState (orderId:int64) (stateId:int64) (credentials:AuthInfo) = 
    // url looks like this: http://www.webstoreexample.com/entity/id
    let auth = BasicAuth credentials.Key ""
    let orderApi = credentials.Api + "/orders/" + orderId.ToString();
    let orderAsXml = Http.RequestString(orderApi, httpMethod = "GET", headers = [auth])
    let xml = Order.Parse(orderAsXml).XElement // at this point, I have the data
    xml.Element(XName.Get("order")).Element(XName.Get("current_state")).SetValue(stateId) // field 'current_state' gets modified
    let xmlData = xml.ToString()
    // HERE the put request
    Http.RequestString(url = credentials.Api + "/orders", 
                       headers = [ auth; 
                                   "Content-Type","text/xml" ],         
                       httpMethod= HttpMethod.Put,
                       body= HttpRequestBody.TextRequest(xmlData))
```

Variations on the PUT-request didn't work as well, here I changed the request body from `TextRequest` into `FormValues`:

```
Http.RequestString(url = credentials.Api + "/orders", 
                   headers = [ auth; 
                               "Content-Type","text/xml" ],         
                   httpMethod= HttpMethod.Put,
                   body= HttpRequestBody.FormValues ["xml", xmlData]) // xml=xmlData
```

Another thing I tried is adding the `id` to the url (even tho in the docs they say that this is not required):

```
Http.RequestString(url = credentials.Api + "/order/" + orderId.ToString(), // added the id to the url
                   headers = [ auth; 
                               "Content-Type","text/xml" ],         
                   httpMethod= HttpMethod.Put,
                   body= HttpRequestBody.FormValues ["xml", xmlData]) // xml=xmlData
```

Specifically, I am tring to the update the value of the `current_state` node of an order. Getting the data and modifying it works as expected but sending the modified data doesn't seem to work and I still recieve the `404: Not found` error

Any Help on this would be greatly apprecited!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with F#, but maybe docs http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service and lib (especially edit() method) https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php will help you

Comment: Do you have an example code in some other language that works?

Comment: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/examples/Update.php it works

Comment: @SergiiP, thanks for your answer, the `edit()` method doesn't help much here as it is called from somewhere else (I don't know from where exactly). I have already seen the Update "example" they have given, unfortunately it only works if you are using the API from the server itself, as they instantiate the `PrestashopWebservice` class in the file and emit some html.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, No I havn't seen any **working** examples yet.

Comment: @ZaidAjaj you can use `class PrestaShopWebservice` on external source, it is just library to make requests/responses easier, and **it works** I used it on several projects. HTML there only for visualization.

Comment: @SergiiP, I am writing a client for Prestashop in F#/C#, I assume there is a way to use php stand-alone on a client, but I would just be polluting my codebase with php code that only makes a web request  that **should be simply replicated** in any other language. Something that is Prestashop-specific is obviously not working.. Here is an example of a 'raw' `PUT` request (from fiddler4).  https://jsfiddle.net/28Lqvccj/1/ Can you tell what why this is not working?

Comment: Do you have an app or PHP example or something else that you can make to work, at least under lab conditions? If so, can you put both requests through Fiddler and see how they differ? This will give you insight into what's wrong.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, thanks for your answer, replicating a working PUT-request should indeed solve the problem but the thing is that I don't write PHP code. But I will look into that soon

Comment: Well, look at it this way: until you have at least _some_ working solution, there is no reason to assume that this can work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just tested it with [library](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php) and [example](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/examples/Update.php) that I give in comments, also I repetead same requests using CURL with same positive results, so there is nothing PHP language specific.
I think you need just repeat same Headers/Body in your application.

```
HTTP REQUEST HEADER
PUT /16011/api/orders/8 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic TlpCUEJKTkhaWFpFMzlCMVBDTkdTM1JQN0s2NTVVQ0Y6
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2411
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

XML SENT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
    <id>8</id>
    <id_address_delivery xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/addresses/5">5</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/addresses/5">5</id_address_invoice>
    <id_cart xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/carts/8">8</id_cart>
    <id_currency xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/currencies/1">1</id_currency>
    <id_lang xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/languages/1">1</id_lang>
    <id_customer xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/customers/2">2</id_customer>
    <id_carrier xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/carriers/3">3</id_carrier>
    <current_state xlink:href="http://localhost/16011/api/order_states/2" notFilterable="true">10</current_state>
    <module>bankwire</module>
    <invoice_number>0</invoice_number>
    <invoice_date>0000-00-00 00:00:00</invoice_date>
    <delivery_number>0</delivery_number>
    <delivery_date>0000-00-00 00:00:00</delivery_date>
    <valid>0</valid>
    <date_add>2015-09-17 08:29:17</date_add>
    <date_upd>2015-10-20 03:45:13</date_upd>
    <shipping_number notFilterable="true"></shipping_number>
    <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
    <secure_key>45838497c9182b0d361473894092de02</secure_key>
    <payment>Bank wire</payment>
    <recyclable>0</recyclable>
    <gift>0</gift>
    <gift_message></gift_message>
    <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
    <total_discounts>0.000000</total_discounts>
    <total_discounts_tax_incl>0.000000</total_discounts_tax_incl>
    <total_discounts_tax_excl>0.000000</total_discounts_tax_excl>
    <total_paid>24.450000</total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl>24.450000</total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl>23.510000</total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real>0.000000</total_paid_real>
    <total_products>16.510000</total_products>
    <total_products_wt>17.170000</total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping>7.280000</total_shipping>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl>7.280000</total_shipping_tax_incl>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl>7.000000</total_shipping_tax_excl>
    <carrier_tax_rate>4.000</carrier_tax_rate>
    <total_wrapping>0.000000</total_wrapping>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl>0.000000</total_wrapping_tax_incl>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl>0.000000</total_wrapping_tax_excl>
    <round_mode>2</round_mode>
    <conversion_rate>1.000000</conversion_rate>
    <reference>ECHCBFWGR</reference>
<associations></associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I replicated the same headers, (see here) https://jsfiddle.net/w51re4bf/ and I still get `404 Error`

Comment: Now I tried the Php webservice, I was able to send GET requests and that worked as expected, the PUT request was sent successfully but this time I got a different error, namely "Bad ID", Please take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/rbq5jza5/2/

Comment: and you have Edit permissions for this api key? etc.

Comment: Yes I do have all permissions, and otherwise I should have gotten a `403: Unauthorized` instead of `404`

Comment: i just tried any ideas, on my side all it works on yours not. I can propose you  only one help, give me the temporary key, I'll check you installation