# How can I PUT a record via Prestashop's webservice (rest api)

Tags: xml, rest, post, prestashop, put

**How can I send a PUT HTTP request, without PHP?**

I have used PHP a heap, but now I writing for a smartphone.  (Using Swift, Java and was C#).  (If asked, I can show the swift code that I use.)

GET is simple, you can also just put the URL in a web browser to get a response.  I have several methods to get customers, addresses, products, etc. and these work well.  (I also have many object models - like a database table structure - that store the data.). (Because JSON is much easier to decode/encode, I apply "&output_format=JSON".  If only I could also PUT / POST JSON...)

POST is also working!  I can GET the blank schema, insert the new details (using plain text) and send (POST) the XML to the URL.  It does it's thing and sends a response containing the inserted record with the details wrapped in CDATA.  (ie. `<abc><![CDATA[input_data]]></abc>` where I want insert input_data in abc)
The response includes the assigned id.  That works fine!

However when it comes to making a PUT (and probably DELETE in the future...) request I keep getting errors.

Using Fiddler, I can view the exact transaction (request & response).

I also used a REST client application (by WizTools.org) and its response was as excepted.

But with PUT - to update the details, I. first GET the record (by id) change as is needed then I PUT the XML back to the same URL.  So it is similar to above, but it fails:

(It would be easier to send JSON instead.)

```
PUT http://example.com/api/customers?ws_key=ABC..XYZ
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: */*
...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
<id>
 ...
</customer>
</prestashop>
```

It responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[127]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[XML error : String could not be parsed as XML
XML length : 0
Original XML : ]]></message>
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

What do I need to send XML, using PUT?

How is the PUT different from POST, what extra steps are needed?

Comment: seems to be a solution here https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/175128-post-request-using-curl-command-line-client/

Comment: and another one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202641/how-to-send-this-put-request-to-prestashop

Comment: @codebrane I tried using *Content-Type: application/x-www-form-encoded; charset=UTF-8* with and without xml=... prefix, response says "String could not be parsed as XML".  (When I read the source code, a while back, it seemed to imply "xml=" prefix is optional). And the First Lady said that either content-type failed as well - however her error was different from mine.  All required fields are filled.  If nothing else works then I'd assume the error is due to some security measure put in place by the hosting company, but GET, POST & DELETE work OK - this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Wireshark indicates the response **501 "String could not be parsed as XML"** is HTTP/XML, that equates to **"Content-Type: text/xml"** header.  However I tried to send the same request as the example in "solution 2" (the order)(using ...form... header), same error again.  Each request gets an ACK.  But still get 501 error!  PS If I miss a required field in a POST request, the response says Bad Passwd, for example - IE explanatory.

Comment: Can you confirm that the XML is actually valid? Try running it through a validator like this. https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ Also, where is the docs for the endpoint you're trying to reach? Perhaps there's a required field that you're missing?

Comment: @colefner "No errors were found".  Moreover I've tried at least 3 resource, each uses different XML elements/properties, and I still get positive results for GET, POST and DELETE.  But always get negative (error 50x) for any PUT request.  Although I like your idea - usually a fundamental issue is at fault.

Comment: Shoot. I was hoping it was something simple (often times is). At this point not much more can be done without knowing the API (or at least having a link to the docs). Can you get ahold of someone at Prestashop support? Or maybe try out their forum? https://www.prestashop.com/forums/

Comment: @colefner I posted to Prestashop forums, no reply yet.  Their doc (for PUT) is very  short - Adding and editing a resource
"To edit an existing resource: GET the full XML file for the resource you want to change (/api/customers/7), edit its content as needed, then PUT the whole XML file back to the same URL again".  One can POST a new record (only needs the required fields), and Prestashop will add it and respond with a complete XML (all fields & attributes).  The response is probably different from the request.  And this process works.

Comment: @YumaTechnicalInc It's tough working with an under-supported API. I wish I could help more. Best of luck!